# Is there any way of reading from stdin on iPhone, either hardware or emulator?

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, ios, console

When I debug an OSX application from XCode, I can communicate with the application's console from the XCode debugging console - for example, the application can `printf()` to `stdout` and that's displayed on the XCode debugging console, and my application can call `fgets()` on `stdin` to which I can type input in the XCode debug console.

It seems like XCode, when debugging iOS iPhone applications, hooks up `stdout` (`printf()` et. al. work fine), but not `stdin`?

Has anyone made `stdin` on iOS/iPhone work? This would be just tremendously useful during debugging - even with an iOS Cocoa app. I could get this to work in some more complicated way, like with a socket, but I'd just rather have XCode do this for me.

UPDATE:

Well, this would explain it. The iOS simulator actually opens `/dev/null` for `stdin`. It's possible to find out where `stdout` is going (typically `/dev/ttys00X`) and then reopen that with `O_RDONLY` and assign it to stdin. This works great for the iOS simulator, but it looks like the line discipline for the serial connection to the iphone hardware is wrong - you can keep typing input in the xcode debug console and it never gets sent to the iphone hardware (and your program running on the iPhone hardware will just sit waiting for something to show up on `stdin` aka `/dev/ttys00X`).

I wonder if there's any way to get this working with the iPhone hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a solution to this exact problem and it's quite possible that there's no way to do that. I have an alternative suggestion. I used it in one of my projects and it worked quite well.

I used the [AsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) library to implement a micro TCP server, which I could connect to using telnet and communicate with my app. There's a few advantages to this approach:

- you don't have to run under the debugger
- the app is accessible from any computer
- it's possible to access the app on somebody else's phone (handy when in a team)
- it's scriptable (can batch multiple commands)
- extendable (easy to make an HTTP server out of this to connect with a browser)

Comment: Yes - I think I'm going to do this anyways. It's fairly useful having a server open on a socket for debugging purposes.